# Selecting strings from database that doesn't have questions marks not at the end

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to select strings from my database which doesn't have question marks that's not at the end. For example:

How? Um?

^---should not be selected, since there is a question mark that's not at the end, in the string.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT response FROM allData WHERE response NOT REGEXP  '[?]\\(?!$\\)'
```

^---My query doesn't work, and is selecting strings with question marks not at the end.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: But your example has a question mark at the end (the corollary of your logic), so it *should* be selected!

Comment: @Strawberry Yeah, my logic hurts my brain, and I can't wrap my head around it. Please show me the correct query to use.

Comment: `locate('?', 'How? Um?') = length('How? Um?')`

Comment: Would 'hello world' be included or excluded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe work for you, try it. :D

```
SELECT response FROM allData WHERE LOCATE('?', response) = LENGTH(response)
```

Comment: Yes! It works! Can you explain how the function works though?

Comment: `LOCATE` finds the first position of a character in a string. If it equals to the length of the string, it is in the last position.

Comment: @frosty Yes, just like sagi said.:D

Comment: Oh, that's awesome! I didn't even know that function existed! Hah.